# Action doesn't come to a head in Asp.Net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action

I have an application **Asp.Net Mvc4**. In my ***Checkout*** controller have a action as follow:

```
 public ActionResult Step1()
    {
        var isEmptyCart = GetCartValue();

        if (!isEmptyCart)
        {
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("AllProduct", "Home");
        }

        return View(new Cart());
    }
 private bool GetCartValue()
    {
        var cart = Session[""];
        if (Session["Cart"] == null || ((Cart)Session["Cart"]).CartItems.Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }


        cart = Session["Cart"];

        ViewData["Cart"] = cart;
        return true;
    }
```

and html *a* tag as follow:

```
<li><a href="@Url.Action("Step1", "Checkout")">Checkout</a></li>
```

When I click this link page refreshes, but ***Step1*** *Action* doesn't execute. I put break point, and see that nothing is happening. I can't resolve this problem about one hour, can't find any reason for this situation,

please help me.

**Edit:**  After refreshing the page it give me ***AllProduct*** action, but my cart isn't empty.

**Edit2:** When I click this link several times, I get following error:

***Cannot create/shadow copy 'EShop.Core' when that file already exists.***

What is it?

Comment: Not sure if it solves your problem, but I'd (if I remember the parameter order correctly) use `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Checkout", "Step1", "Checkout")</li>`

Comment: @Elvin Arzumanoğlu - I would check generated link and try the url in browser. Sometimes it is routing issue.

Comment: It is very strange:(, I can't resolve it, a day before it work very well. Ok I will try it now.

Comment: Doesn't work,@Joachim Isaksson. Thank you for reply

Comment: There are Step2, Step3 and Step4 actions in the same controller and they work fine. If it is routing issue, How do they  work?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your problem is related to browser cache : You are using a permanent redirection in the Step1 Action ([RedirectToActionPermanent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoactionpermanent%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)) and this kind of redirection is cached for certain browser like Chrome or Firefox. (see more information in [here](http://getluky.net/2010/12/14/301-redirects-cannot-be-undon/)).

It could explain why it worked yesterday and why it is directly sending you to your AllProduct action today (instead of hitting breakpoints set into your Step1 action).

Perhaps you can try to reset/clean your browser cache and test again to see what happens.
Hope this will help.

Comment: It is very precise answer, thank you. Now I have other question that How can I substitute RedirectToAction?

Comment: I think a simple RedirectToAction instead of RedirectToActionPermanent would be enough. RedirectToActionPermanent generates a HTTP response containing a '301 Moved Permanently' status code that is used for permanent redirection (which often involves caching, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). On the other hand, RedirectToAction generates a HTTP response containing a '302 Moved Temporarily' status code which is more suited to what you are looking to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,@Airl. I clean session from all browser and it work fine now.

Comment: Thank you for saving my day :)